# SlickGrid Filter returns strange results

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

Requirement called for SlickGrid filtering via a button click rather than default autocomplete so I modified the updateFilter() method just so ('#display' is the button ID):

```
$('#display').click(function() {
    updateFilter();
});

     function updateFilter() {
        theString = $('#txtSearch').val();
        while(theString.substring(0,1)==" ")
             theString = theString.substring(1, theString.length);
        searchString = new String(theString);
            dataView.setFilterArgs({
                searchString:searchString,
            });
            dataView.refresh();
      }
```

Pretty simple... I just grab the value in the textbox when the button is clicked then I make sure it's a string and pass it to "searchString" for processing.  What you'll notice is that I also had to trim a leading space or the filter would consistently fail to first time through.  Firebug trace would show " 57", for example, rather than the actual "57".  This would cause the return to clear the grid (I assume because it couldn't match the leading space). 
Requirement also called for a "Clear Filter" link which reset the filter (including the "#txtSearch" textbox).  The filter would always work after it was cleared and trace showed no leading space.
Both theString and searchString were initialized at top of script (="").  My question is, why does this happen and where does the leading space it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... self inflicted wound.  Turns out that I initialized the textbox with value=" ".  Sorry!